# Web Api Batch Request Hosted in IIS Returns 404 for Inner URLs

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've been developing a RESTful API using Web Api 2 and as part of it I implemented batch requests using JSON objects as described in one of their wiki articles (https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web+API+Request+Batching).

This process went smoothly enough while testing using IIS Express, but when I deployed the application in IIS 8 under an IIS application the batch requests no longer function properly. Every sub request returns 404 not found even when the url points to the proper location. However, this only happens when the program is deployed as an application under an IIS website. If you simply drop the program into the root of an IIS website batching behaves correctly.

I have some images of the failure / success responses in Fiddler, but SO won't let me post them. So as an example, a batch POST request made to the IIS website hosted at "http:// domain.com/api/v1.0/" with the inner url set to "realtimedata/queues?queueIds=1" works fine, but when the app is accessible at "http:// domain.com/test/api/v1.0/" the same request with the same inner url returns 404, even though "http:// domain.com/test/api/v1.0/realtimedata/queues?queueIds=1" is a perfectly valid address that can be called fine without using the batch request. (The space in between "http" and "domain in the example urls is just to get around SO's link limit, so imagine they aren't there). Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more testing, I found that this was an issue particular to hosting via OWIN in IIS. I had to register my routes against the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration object instead of a new’d up Configuration object and then the 404’s were resolved. I’m not sure why this was the case, but it worked.

Comment: Hmmm, I had same issue without OWIN, and I used `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` to. In any case, the solution that I [gave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376233/web-api-batch-request-hosted-in-iis-returns-404-for-inner-urls/30101356#30101356) works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add/modify **system.webServer** section in your web.config according to this sample:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Please note, that `path="/*"` replaced with `path="*."` in **add** tag.